# Access delete method body send via axios.delete

Tags: python, reactjs, django, axios, request

I am building a react-django simple blog app and I am trying to delete blog post but I also want to send body with delete to backend But I have no idea, `How can I access delete body ?`. I can do with post like `self.request.POST` with how with `delete` ?

App.js:

```
class BlogPost extends React.Component {
    deleteBlog = (blog_title) => {
     const body = ({title: blog_title});

      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        Accept: "application/json",
      }
     

     axios.delete("delete_blog/", blog_title, {headers:headers}).then(res => {console.log})
    }


    render() {
     return (
        <div>
            {
               this.state.blogs.map(res => <div>
                  {res.blog_title}
                  <button onClick={() => deleteBlog(res.blog_title)}></button>


                </div>
            }
        </div>
   

)}}
```

views.py:

```
class BlogPost(APIView):

    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        .......

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Trying to access delete body here......

        print(self.request.POST)
        # It printed empty dict like <[QueryDict = {}]>
```

I have tried many times but it is still not showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Use Axios Delete request with body , you need to use axios.delete(url,{ headers: { "Authorization": "***" },  data: {  } } );

eg:

```
axios.delete("delete_blog/", {
  headers: headers,
  data: {
    source: blog_title
  }
});
```

Comment: It is not working

Comment: I had updated the answer & its working..

Comment: Okay But how do I access this `delete body` in django view ?

Comment: you can access it from the request body of the api..                                                                                eg:  req.body.data.source